# First install of PostgreSQL on Windows Server - How to enable / test remote access?

Tags: postgresql

I'm installing PostgreSQL on a Windows 2008r2 Server, with the intention to use with a Delphi 7 application over ODBC.

I followed the [PostgreSQL 12.2 Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/index.html)
Not needing to install from source as described in chapter 17, I opted for the [Installer that was linked to](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)
Following the guidance of the [Installation Guide (Installers)](http://Installation%20Guide%20(Installers))  I completed the install process without errors.

After restarting the server, I can see the service postgresql-12-x64 is running.

I created the user postres, and was able to start the commandline using runas:

```
c:\>runas /user:postgres "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql.exe"
Enter the password for postgres:
Attempting to start C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql.exe as user "****\postgres" ...
```

The installer apparently did not update the path, so I had to provide the full path. 
Now I have a command window on the server machine with a postgres-# prompt.

Next, I want to verify that I can connect to the server from another machine. 
[Posts I find](https://docs.bitnami.com/google-templates/infrastructure/postgresql/administration/connect-remotely/) say to use a command like:

```
psql -h SERVER-IP -U postgres
```

However, psql.exe is installed on the server not the client machine.  What is a "test" executable that can be run from the client to verify that it is able to communicate with the server? Is it as simple as copying psql.exe from the server's C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin folder to a temp folder on the client? I tried that and psql.exe closes without any output or error indication:

```
H:\temp>ping 192.168.2.1
Pinging 192.168.2.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.2.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128    
^C
H:\temp>psql -h 192.168.2.1 -U postgres

H:\temp>
```

Comment: This site https://www.compose.com/articles/postgresql-tips-installing-the-postgresql-client/  shows that the client install is accomplished with the full Windows installer, and selecting only the "Command Line Tools"

Comment: After installing the Command Line Tools on the client, I now get: H:\temp>psql -h 192.168.2.1 -U postgres      "psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)"